# How do I get JQuery Autocomplete to work with Ajax and JSON?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete

I am new to JQuery's autocomplete functionality.  I am trying to get this code to work correctly.  The code below correctly does an ajax poll every time someone types into the input field.  However it does't drop down the autocomplete.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: 'cityajax'
  });
});
```

Here is the file it is successfully pulling from the server.  The mime/content type is set to text/json.

```
['Overland Park','Hiawatha','Columbus','Lenexa','Pittsburg','Dodge City','Mission']
```

The same thing works fine when actual the source is set to an inline JSON var in the javascript itself.  This problem has got to be something stupid simple, but I have spent the past hour and half trying to figure out what's wrong and I'm at a roadblock.  Am I missing some kind of required parameter?

EDIT: Changed my "json" to this valid JSON, still same issue.

```
{"1": "Overland Park","1": "Hiawatha","1": "Columbus","1": "Lenexa","1": "Pittsburg","1": "Dodge City"}
```

EDIT: Changed my "json" again to this.

```
[{"1": "Overland Park"},{"2": "Hiawatha"},{"3": "Columbus"},{"4": "Lenexa"},{"5": "Pittsburg"},{"6": "Dodge City"}]
```

EDIT: Changed my "json" to this and everything was good.

[{"label": "Overland Park"},{"label": "Hiawatha"},{"label": "Columbus"},{"label": "Lenexa"},{"5": "Pittsburg"},{"label": "Dodge City"}]

Comment: JSON is not an array, but always wrapped in `{...}`. You'd need to fetch the data, parse the array out of it and pass that array to `.autocomplete`.

Comment: Try this: [{'label':'Overland..'},{'label':'Anonymus'}], Beside the 1,2,3 use label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you used is definitely not going to work.  I'd question how you know the data is definitely getting there.  Are you seeing it in XHR via Firebug?  How are you calling it if you're not using the plugin's remote source functionality?

The way you've got it defined, there's no file extension.  So, it's setting the source to a string called cityajax, which isn't valid.  If your datasource is a variable called cityajax, then you could put that variable there without the quotes.

[Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) will allow you to test the validity of your data.

Comment: This is in Kohana MVC framework, there is no .php extension so it is valid and the call is coming through in net view on Firebug.  I changed around my "json" to this valid JSON.

{'1': 'Overland Park','1': 'Hiawatha','1': 'Columbus','1': 'Lenexa','1': 'Pittsburg','1': 'Dodge City'}

Comment: This JSON is not good, try this [{'label':'Overland..'},{'label':'Anonymus'}]

Comment: In the end my problem was just not having valid JSON, upvote for Jsonlist, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example for the autocomplet:

```
$( "#test" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php"
                        })
```

In the search.php

```
<?php
    echo [{"label":"Overland Park"},{"label":"Hiawatha"}]
?>
```

If you want a local search, not Ajax than use the following code

```
var cityajax = ['Overland Park','Hiawatha','Columbus','Lenexa','Pittsburg','Dodge City','Mission']

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: cityajax
  });
});
```

Comment: In the end my problem was just not having valid JSON.